# How to use multi dimentional array of objects in angular JS?

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I am trying to create a multi dimensional array in angular JS and push objects into it.

Below is my code snippet -

```
$scope.dm.Questionnaires.Q_options=[][][];
for(var i in data)
{
    if(data[i].dbObject.fieldname=="Q0001") {
        $scope.dm.Questionnaires.Q_options[1][1].push(data[i].dbObject);
    }
    else if(data[i].dbObject.fieldname=="Q0002") {
        $scope.dm.Questionnaires.Q_options[2][1].push(data[i].dbObject);
    }
}
```

Trying to access the array in html as below -

```
<select class="input-md form-control" ng-model="dm.Questionnaires.Q1000101" ng-options="item.antHillValue for item in dm.Questionnaires.Q_options[1][1] track by item.webServiceValue">
<option value="">select</option>
</select>
```

I am not able to get this working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Declaration of array is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this.

```
$scope.dm = {};
$scope.dm.Questionnaires = {};
$scope.dm.Questionnaires.Q_options = [[[]]];

$scope.dm.Questionnaires.Q_options[0][0].push(1);

......
```

You must check if array at any index exists or not.

```
if ($scope.dm.Questionnaires.Q_options[index] == null ) {
      $scope.dm.Questionnaires.Q_options[index] = [];
}
```